# JDBC: PL/SQL object (procedure) is invalid

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sqlplus

JDBC: PL/SQL object (procedure) is invalid.

```
String sql = "create procedure foo(name varchar2) as " +
"begin " +
...
"end";

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
stmt.close();


String sql1 = "begin foo('world'); end;";
CallableStatement s = connection.prepareCall(sql1);
s.execute();
s.close();
```

ERROR when executing the second SQL:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object MY_DB.FOO is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

MY_DB is current connection user.
After the 1st statement, the procedure is not found by `desc Foo` from sqlplus.

NO error if running these two statements in sqlplus.

Comment: What is the error message you get if you run `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;` after you've tried to create the procedure?

Comment: Is the semicolon (;) required at the end of SQL statement?  Appending (;) to the SQL solved the problem. But it seems that regular SQL statements in JDBC does not require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A semi-colon is required to terminate every PL/SQL statement, declaration & block.
- The outermost PL/SQL block is usually also terminated by a slash `/` character.
- In contrast, each atomic item of SQL code is a single statement and is typically terminated by a semi-colon `;` character.

In SQL/Plus (and SQL Developer) the terminating characters are used to signify ends of executable pieces of code (and depending on the user interface's settings a blank line can do this too) and the start of the next.

In JDBC, when you invoke a piece of code you do not need the terminating character as each call only contains a single statement (for SQL) or (outer) block (for PL/SQL) and the terminator would be redundant. So for a PL/SQL statement being called via JDBC, you do not need the `/` to terminate the code but you do require the `;` to terminate the statements, declaraions & block(s) that the code is comprised of (including the outer-most `BEGIN`/`END` block).

So your code should be:

```sql
String sql = "create procedure foo(name varchar2) as " +
"begin " +
...
"end;";
```